# Page Cannot Be Requested EXCEPT By A Certain Other Page.

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is there any way to have for example:

```
**result.php**
```

Only work if requested by:

```
**input.php**
```

Otherwise throw an error.

Obvious NO direct access to result.php but also NO access from any other page except input.php.

Is this something that can be accomplished and how? I've tried googling things like "limit page access to specific other page" etc.. but it yield nothing relevant, just unrelated stuff like changing chmod etc and this is not what I'm after.

Many thanks for any help.... Or at least pointer on how I should formulate the question.

Comment: What do you mean, "requested by" `input.php`? Do you mean that you want to check the [referrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)?

Comment: Sorry - to clarify - when you have a link from input.php going to result.php. So otherwise it should not work directly or from other page. Yes, I've just looked at the link you posted - I guess the referrer would be it, just have to figure out how.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, `debug_backtrace` is what your after - http://au1.php.net/debug_backtrace - This will return an associative array and you can do a check to ensure results.php was called by the file input.php.

The problem with this is that the file will return the full address of your file (i.e. /Applications/MAMP/program/input.php) so when you deploy to another server the expected result will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to prevent people from accidentally opening the wrong page, [referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) checking is sufficient.  The HTTP `Referer` header contains the URL of the page that linked to the one being requested, so in your `result.php` code, you can check that the referer is the correct URL for your `input.php` page.

However, the referer header is sent by the client (e.g. browser), so you're relying on it to tell you the truth.  A skilled user can request your `result.php` page with a fake referer header that *says* they came from `input.php` when they really didn't.  This is called [referer spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing).

If you need to prevent that, for security reasons, then you need to use PHP's [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) support to keep track *on the server* of which steps the user has completed so far, so that when the user tries to access `result.php`, you can check for the prerequisites in a way that can't easily be spoofed.